# When a Shopify store customer has logged in to his account on the store I want also make him log into my Shopify app

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have developed a Shopify app, I wonder if we can perform the following functionality :
when a customer has logged in to his account on the store I want to also log him into my app, in another word I want to make a customer account is the same as his account on my app.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you know. A customer logged into a Shopify store has a visible ID to Javascript. You could thus use an **App Proxy** to securely pass back their ID to your App. Using that ID, you can offer functionality to that customer, in your App. As long as you restrict access to the Proxy, you'd be A-Ok security wise.

If you wanted to allow access to the App without Proxy calls, you'll have to put into place your own security, which as we know from experience, will likely be weak and or a calamity. Most people should never roll their own security patterns. If they login to the App, without Shopify Plus Multipass, you cannot log them into Shopify. So you have no other options AFAIK.